# SQL Server transactional replication performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I have an issue with SQL Server transactional replication performance. The published articles are on a database which is being used quite heavily however i am not convinced the replication is should be going this slow and I could use some advice on interpreting the information from replication monitor.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Alx37tO.png]
[image]

[image]

I have noticed that the distributor agent has a delivery rate of 0 which concerns me.
Can someone explain what the following information means in real terms and how i can go about improving the performance of replication?

Comment: Check that the distribution agent isn't being blocked at the subscriber. This is no different than checking blocking for any other application. Next, trace the performance of any stored procedures called by the distribution agent. Make sure that they have reasonable execution times for what they're doing. Know that the "estimated delivery time" is notoriously bad. Also, getting the count of undistributed commands isn't cheap. I recommend dropping tracer tokens at a periodic interval to monitor replication.